# How does 301 redirect with MASKING work?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I've been playing with 301 redirection with masking with the purpose of sending newdomain.com to hostingdomain.com without the user noticing (transparent redirection). However all available referrer data seems to be missing. For instance I cannot use:

```
<?php echo parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST); ?>
```

or

```
document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = document.referrer; // nothing
document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = location; // domain hosting files
```

They all give me hostingdomain.com's (the domain hosting the files) URL data. Please help me come up with a solution to transparently send my domains to my one hosted domain and be able to grab the original domain's data for use in heading tags and such.

Comment: unless newdomain.com and hostingdomain.com are on the same server, you're going to have to issue a client-side redirect. the only way to mask the url is to use a frame/iframe so that the browser's address bar doesn't change, but the status bar will show requests to hostingdomain.com anyways. That or you turn your server into a full proxy for hostingdomain...

Comment: Referer is not working with MASKED 301 redirection. The same server may work. However, how do I do a 301 redirect WITH masking in htaccess?